# How to find the minimum value in an array in a given range?

Tags: arrays

We are give 2 arrays, one array is called the original array and other is the corresponding array.

Example :

> a: `[5,6,5,7,5,5,5,8,9]`
>
> a': `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1]`

We are given 3 values:
`l`,`r` and `x`

Let `l = 3` and `r = 7`, also `x = 5`,

So we check the occurrences of `5` in the range `[3,7]` , so
`a[3]`, `a[5]`, `a[6]`, `a[7]` are the indices which contain `5`.

Now, we check the corresponding array's values, `a'[3]`, `a'[5]`, `a'[6]`, `a'[7]` which are: `3`, `2`, `3` and `1`. The minimum of these is `1` and hence the output will be : `1`.

I know the brute-force approach for multiple queries like this, but I'm interested in an efficient approach !

Comment: Which language are you using first ?

Answer (score 0):

Optimized way to find the minimum value, checking the value of `x` in the range `l` & `r`, it the value is present then comparing it with the previous minimum value of `x` found in `aDash` array.

```
public static void minimumValue(int[] a, int aDash[], int l, int r, int x) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean isValueFound = false;
    for(int i = l-1; i<a.length && i<r; i++) {
        if(a[i] == x && aDash[i] < min) {
            min = aDash[i];
            isValueFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(isValueFound)
        System.out.println(min);
    else {
        //do something when no value of x is present in the array 'a'
    }
}
```